# Rename files using python

Tags: python

I want to rename a file from say {file1} to {file2}. I read about `os.rename(file1,file2)` in python and is able to do so.

I succeeded only when the the file is placed in the same folder as python script, so I want to ask how can we rename files of other folders i.e. different folder than the one in which python script is placed.

Comment: you need use full path.

Comment: note: there is also os.replace, os.renames functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the full path, instead of the relative path:

```
oldFile = 'C:\\folder\\subfolder\\inFile.txt'
newFile = 'C:\\foo\\bar\\somewhere\\other\\outFile.txt'

os.rename(oldFile, newFile)
```

To get the double-slash behavior, you can do the following

```
import os
oldFile = r'C:\folder\subfolder\inFile.txt'  # note the r character for raw string
os.path.normpath(oldFile)
```

Output

```
'C:\\folder\\subfolder\\inFile.txt'
```

Comment: Actually I tried this, and on my system it didn't work, what worked is using \\ instead of \.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Maybe you needed to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Yes you are correct, you need double backslashes, that was my mistake.

Comment: If you know, can you please edit the answer with the function used to convert \ to \\.

Comment: Please see my most recent edit. This uses the `os.path.normpath` function to create a path.

Comment: you can also use `/` and r which will work on unix and windows

Comment: @Cyber Actually the new name of the file has a '/' in it and normpath() changes it to '\' which results into incorrect path.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you need to use full path.

On the other note, take a look at [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) documentation, it can also be used for renaming.